# How would you write this exponent statement in PHP?

Tags: php

How would I write this exponent  in PHP?

```
( ( ( ( (3) ^2 ) ^2 ) ^2 ) ^2 )
```

I took a general programming test that had a problem similar to this where you had to use an algorithm they provided to write a recursive function to return the result. The numbers in question here would be `3` and <strike>8</strike> `16`.

Comment: What do you mean by write ? you mean call a function that returns the correct result ? or set this operation in a variable ?

Comment: `echo pow(pow(pow(pow(3, 2), 2), 2), 2);`

Comment: the answer I get from this is 43046721. I don't know what you mean by "The numbers in question here would be 3 and 8"

Comment: What numbers would be 3 and 8? 3^2 is not 8, but 2^3 is...

Comment: I think OP means `3` and `16` (`3^16` == `(((3^2)^2)^2)^2`)

Comment: @SmokeyPHP - exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use pow method the code for, what you want to do can be written as -

```
pow(pow(pow(pow(3,2),2),2),2)
```

See the documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pow.php)

Answer (score 3):

See PHP's [`pow`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pow.php) function (short for power, aka exponent)

Comment: Why was this downvoted, I wonder?

Answer (score 1):

Using the native [pow function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pow.php):

```
pow(pow(pow(pow(3, 2), 2), 2), 2);
```